# How to run protractor suites with multiple users

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Below is my config file that I use to run a single user and multiple test suite.Now, am having a issue where I want to run few protractor suites with User A and few protractor test suite with User B. I don't know how to achieve this in protractor.

```js
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  suites: {
    loginAndNavigate: 'e2e/specFiles/LoginAndNavigateSpec.js',
    homepage: 'e2e/specFiles/policiesList_HomepageSpec.js',
    versionPage: 'e2e/specFiles/ER_VersionsPageSpec.js'
    policyDetails: 'e2e/specFiles/policyDetailsPageSpec.js'
  },
  seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar',
  chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.26',
  baseUrl: 'https://shared.qa.com/EdgeAuth/logindirect.jsp',
  params: {
    login: {
      user: ‘user ',
      password: 'abc123'
    }
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    global.EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.getCapabilities().then(function(c) {
      console.log(c.get('browserName'));
    });
    global.Utils = require('./e2e/utils.js');
    require('./e2e/matchers.js');
    require('./e2e/customLocators.js');
  },
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide new param (user details) and suite details when you run the test.

For the params object use `--params.login.user "User B"` etc etc to overwrite config file details.

For the suites you can use `--suite=loginAndNavigate` or if more than one then `--suite=loginAndNavigate,homepage` to choose what to run.

You will need the proper combination of these two to suit your needs.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

Comment: Is there a way that both users can be passed via config.js file without passing it as argument and overriding it. Reason I am asking this is I have a jenkins job that runs somke tests. Now, I would like to run these smoke test suite with multiple users and passing as an argument will make it run as one user. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: You can give the params object an array of user objects. But then your login suite will need to handle this to choose which user to use. Or if you are restricted to two users you can use a hack like user1name and user2name etc.

Comment: So, if I am using params array object and then in my login test suite. trying to use User A login details. It is entering "undefined instead.

`params: {
login: [{
user: 'userA',
password: 'abc123'
},
{ user1:'UserB',
password1:'abc123'
}
]
},`

Here is how I am using it in my test
`browser.params.login.user`

Comment: browser.params.login.user - This will try to get the 'user' property of the login array, which it does not have. Use browser.params.login[0].user

Comment: It was a very silly mistake. Thanks it's working. Will test your suggested way   of using params array object to see if it solves my problem completely.

Comment: Also, How will I set up my tests so that it uses and runs simultaneously or one after the other for both usernames.
For ex: loginAndNavigate, homepage runs for UserA once its done it goes back and run same test for UserB

Comment: If you are planning to run the same tests with just different login values then you are better off using this package instead of values in config file - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider. If you are looking for different tests with different logins, I would create separate smoke specs and in that pass the desired login values to a common login function. You can even divide into two different suite.